# ASP.NET MVC routing '/category/{string}' instead of '/category/details/{string}'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a route to access my categories like so: `/category/{id}` instead of `/category/details/{id}`.

I've tried many possible examples like so

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Category",
    "category/{id}",
    new { controller = "category", action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "Project.Controllers" }
);
```

but it does not seem to work. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my controller with action

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            return Content(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did everything correctly, I just placed it below my default route, need to put new routs **above** default one.

Comment: so you see the main problem was that you didn't provide enough information in your question. Otherwise it would be obvious that your routes are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

At first look it correct, but you also can have another routes, it depends on position. Use Glimpse to debug your application: 
[NuGet Package of the Week #5 - Debugging ASP.NET MVC applications with Glimpse](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on my local machine
localhost/Category/Details/1

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Category", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional     } // Parameter defaults
        );



public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Category/

    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

or are you doing HttpGet or HttpPost?

Comment: `/category/details/1` works for me as well, what I need is `/category/1` to work.